# Datastore - Unable to Write Entities on Datastore using Dataflow Job

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I have CSV file in the **GCP Bucket**, which I need to move to the **Google Cloud Datastore**. The CSV Shape format is (60000, 6). Using cloud **Dataflow** I wrote a Pipeline and moved into the datastore. The Dataflow Job is Successfully Completed. But when I check the data in data store there are no entities. This is the Pipeline image for your reference. 
[image: Pipeline Image]

and the pool node graph is here.
[image: Worker Pool Node Graph].

From the pipeline Graph, I came to know that it didn't do any job on creating an Entities and writing into the datastore**(0 secs)**.

To do this job, I have referred this tutorial [Uploading CSV File to The Datastore](https://www.the-swamp.info/blog/uploading-data-cloud-datastore-using-dataflow/).

It will be more helpful if I get to know where the pipeline went wrong?

Comment: what errors/warnings are you getting? It seems the job didn't even start. Have you checked the Google's template for [GCS text to Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates#cloud-storage-text-to-cloud-datastore)? If you transform the CSV to text you could use it, or at least get an idea of the code.

Comment: did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: Yes! Found another method to do this job. :)

Comment: Now facing another issue can you help me to resolve this? Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52511894/gcp-get-all-entities-from-the-datastore

Comment: Were my recommendations helpful? Could you please add how you solved your issue as an answer, so if people with the same issue know how to solve it?

Comment: Since my dataset is not too big. I  just used Batch Operation `put_multi([task_1, task_2])` to insert data once into the datastore.