# gcp - get all entities from the datastore

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to get all data entities from the datastore. When I came across google docs I found something similar to **Query Projection** ([Link to the Docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries)). This is the code I used to get all entities from the datastore.

```
def do_the_query_projection(self, kind_name):

        query = self.client.query(kind=kind_name)
        query.projection = ['attr_1', 'attr_2', 'attr_3']

        #create a list to store
        f, m, r = [], [], []

        for task in query.fetch():
            f.append(task['attr_1'])
            m.append(task['attr_2'])
            r.append(task['attr_3'])

        return f, m, r
```

This is the Error I am facing now

```
> google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 no matching index
> found. recommended index is:
> - kind: <kind_name>  properties:
>   - name: attr_1
>   - name: attr_2
>   - name: attr_3
```

Is there any other method to retrieve all data entities from the Cloud Datastore? Do we need to create the composite Indexes to retrieve the data? I am new to the GCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve all entities in the datastore

```
def retrieve_all_entities(self):
    query = self.client.query(kind=self.kind_name)
    all_keys = query.fetch() #fetches all the entities from the datastore

    kinds, r, m, f = [] , [], [], []

    for keys in all_keys:
        kinds.append(keys.key.id_or_name)
        r.append(keys['attr_1'])
        m.append(keys['attr_2'])
        f.append(keys['attr_3'])

    return kinds, r, m, f
```

Comment: This is terribly inefficient, because this code makes 4 round-trips to the Datastore to fetch 3 entities, while this can be done in one round-trip. Why do you need a keys-only query first?

Comment: For the performance process can we use something like `key_all(kind)` to get all the entities? Instead of getting the key entity first and iterate through all the keys to get remaining properties!

Answer (score 2):

Try making a query without a projection.

Projection queries are useful when you already have a composite index on the columns you want to retrieve, because it allows you to retrieve these columns from the index without retrieving anything from the data table.  If you don't have the index, however, the Datastore would have to retrieve the full data either way, so it doesn't allow you to specify a projection in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot provide any sample code because I have not used this Python API (only the [old Datastore API on App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/). Probably removing the line with `query.projection = [...]` should do the trick

Comment: I figured another way to do this job. Thanks for the help!